# NSTextView inside NSView and NSScrollView

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstextview

My goal is to make a view that is similar to the Goole Docs text editor, with comment highlighting behind the text where there are comments.
[image: Highlight]

My solution is to have an `NSScrollView` containing an `NSView` (set as the document view) that scrolls and contains both an `NSTextView` of the text, and other `NSView`s that will be the highlights.

For this to work, the `NSTextView` has to size as if it belongs directly to the `NSScrollView`. However, I cannot make the `NSTextView` have this behavior.

The code I have for the layout is:

***LatinViewController:loadView()***

```
...
let latinView = LatinView()
latinView.autoresizingMask = [.ViewWidthSizable]
latinView.wantsLayer = true
latinView.layer?.backgroundColor = Theme.greenColor().CGColor
self.latinView = latinView
scrollView.documentView = latinView
...
```

***LatinView:init()***

```
...
let textView = LatinTextView()
textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
textView.string = "Long string..."
self.addSubview(textView)
self.textView = textView

self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[text]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["text": textView]))
self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[text]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["text": textView]))
...
```

***LatinTextView:init()***

```
...
self.minSize = NSMakeSize(0, 0)
self.maxSize = NSMakeSize(0, CGFloat(FLT_MAX))
self.verticallyResizable = true
self.horizontallyResizable = false
self.textContainer?.heightTracksTextView = false
...
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

From your requirements it appears you can achieve the functionality simply by using NSAttributedString and a NSTextView. Following is the sample code
A NSTextView already comes with rich text editing functionality and format storage can be achieved through a NSAttributedString

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet var textView:NSTextView!


    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        let singleAttribute1 = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: NSColor.purpleColor() , NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: NSColor.yellowColor() ]

        let multipleAttributes = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: NSColor.redColor(),
            NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleDouble.rawValue ]

        var string1 = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello World", attributes: singleAttribute1)

        var string2 = NSAttributedString(string: " This is knowstack", attributes: multipleAttributes)

        var finalString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: string1)
        finalString.appendAttributedString(string2)

        self.textView.textStorage?.setAttributedString(finalString)

    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }


    @IBAction func getAttributedString(sender:AnyObject){
        var attributedString = self.textView.attributedString()
        print(attributedString)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`NSLayoutManager` (which is used by `NSTextView`, and `NSAttributedString` in general) has a special feature designed for altering text before displaying it on screen without changing the source: temporary attributes.

Look up `NSLayoutManager` docs for methods that have "TemporaryAttribute" in their names:

```
- (void)addTemporaryAttribute:(NSString *)attrName value:(id)value forCharacterRange:(NSRange)charRange
```

They are supposed to be used for instance as green/red underlining of words during spellcheck, or to simply highlight a portion of text temporarily. They allow you to modify appearance of portions of text for mere display purposes without modifying the original attributed text source.

Comment: This looks like a great solution. Another solution I thought of was to just add `CALayer` instances beneath the main `NSTextLayer` layer on the `NSTextView` to show highlighting, but this solution looks better. What do you think?